# matching of columns between two pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, match

```
import pandas as pd
temp1 = pd.DataFrame(index=arange(10), columns=['a','b'])
temp1['a'] = [1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,9,11]
temp1['b'] = 'B'

temp2 = pd.DataFrame(index=arange(10), columns=['a','b'])
temp2['a'] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
temp2['b'] = 'B'
```

As the script above, I want to pickup rows from `temp1` that column `a` was not seen at `temp2`. I can use `%in%` in R to do it easily, how can I do it in pandas?

#### update 01

the output should be one row which column `a` is `11` and column `b` is `B`

Comment: Can you post desired output just to clarify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) to perform boolean indexing:

`isin` will produce a boolean index:

```
In [95]:

temp1.a.isin(temp2.a)
Out[95]:
0     True
1     True
2     True
3     True
4     True
5     True
6     True
7     True
8     True
9    False
Name: a, dtype: bool
```

This can then be used as a mask in the final output:

```
In [94]:
# note the ~ this negates the result so equivalent of NOT
temp1[~temp1.a.isin(temp2.a)]
Out[94]:
    a  b
9  11  B
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) to get the indices that *are* seen, and then negate the boolean indices:

```
temp1[~temp1.a.isin(temp2.a)]
```